# Error calling JSTimersExecution.callTimers in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

I am stuck with this error type in react-native. please find the attached screenshot. Please guide me to solve this error.

[image]

I am using 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0